# SELECT with WHERE and CASE

Tags: mysql

I do not really know if this is possible to do this but I will expose my problem.

I have two tables `cases` and `progress`

cases

```
+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------+
| id_cases |     name     |    date_surgery     | archive | done |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------+
|        1 | Cranioplasty | 2016-02-01 00:00:00 |       1 |    0 |
|        2 | Cranioplasty | 2016-02-02 00:00:00 |       0 |    0 |
|        3 | Other        | 2016-02-03 00:00:00 |       0 |    0 |
|        4 | Osteotomy    | 2016-02-04 00:00:00 |       0 |    0 |
|        5 | Bone Tumor   | 2016-02-05 00:00:00 |       1 |    1 |
+----------+--------------+---------------------+---------+------+
```

progress (which contains thousands of records)

```
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
| id_progress | task_id | case_id | current |
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
|           1 |  103006 |       1 |       0 |
|           2 |  103002 |       1 |       1 |
|           3 |  103003 |       1 |       1 |
|           4 |  201006 |       5 |       0 |
|           5 |  201007 |       5 |       1 |
|        .... |     ... |     ... |      ...|
+-------------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The link between the tables is `cases.id_cases = progress.case_id`

I want to select all cases with archive and done = 0. I also want to get some progress that are linked to this case

I tought about a condition to select a specific range of task_id related to the result of cases.name.

So basically I want this

```
SELECT id_cases, name, date_surgery, task_id, current
FROM cases 
LEFT JOIN progress on progress.case_id = cases.id_cases 
WHERE archive = 0 AND done = 0
```

But if name is Cranioplasty I just want progress.task_id that are equal to 103006, 103002. For Bone Tumor I want 201006 and 205003. And this for all the different name.

There is no logic between the id_cases and the task_id. I must hardcode this.

I tried differents things but none suceeded

```
SELECT id_Cases, name, date_surgery, task_id, current
from cases 
left join progress on progress.case_id = cases.id_cases 
where archive = 0 and done = 0 
and case when name='Cranioplasty' then task_id=103006 and task_id=103002 else
case when name='Bone Tumor' then task_id=201006 else
case when name='Osteotomy' then task_id=301002 else
case when name='MBIO' then task_id=401006 end end end end 
order by name, date_surgery
```

In fine I try to get this result (`task_id` is not important, I just want to result of `current`)

```
+------+--------------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| case |     name     | date_surg | task_1 | 1_res | task_2 | 2_res | task_3 | 3_res |
+------+--------------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
| 1    | Cranioplasty | date      | 103006 |     0 | 103002 |     0 | 105002 |     1 |
| 1    | Cranioplasty | date      | 103006 |     1 | 103002 |     1 | 105002 |     0 |
| 1    | Cranioplasty | date      | 103006 |     1 | 103002 |     0 | 105002 |     1 |
| 2    | Cranioplasty | date      | 103006 |     0 | 103002 |     1 | 105002 |     0 |
| 2    | Cranioplasty | date      | 103006 |     1 | 103002 |     0 | 105002 |     1 |
| 2    | Cranioplasty | date      | 103006 |     0 | 103002 |     1 | 105002 |     1 |
| 3    | Bone Tumor   | date      | 201006 |     1 | 205003 |     0 | 205005 |     0 |
| 3    | Bone Tumor   | date      | 201006 |     0 | 205003 |     1 | 205005 |     1 |
| ...  |              |           |        |       |        |       |        |       |
+------+--------------+-----------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: `For Bone Tumor I want 201006 and 205003` where is  205003 in your sample data?

Comment: @Mihai  I just put this example to help understand the problem. It does not includes all the records

Comment: You could put the pairs of *"allowed"* `(name, task_id)` to a separate table instead.

Comment: @jkavalik I wanted to know if this is possible to resolve my problem without creating any new table. If performance are better by creating a new table instead of executing the query, I would add a table.

Comment: @Raccoon you could use a temporary table or even a *virtual* one (`select val from (select 1 as val union select 2 union select 3) as tmp` is valid for instance). But what you want should be possible, the key is that the CASE has to return 0/1, and all the comparisons have to be in the conditions part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with the query you listed:

1. In the first test, you use and `AND` instead of an `OR` or an `IN` (I perfer `IN` -- in fact, I would prefer it in all cases so that it is easy to extend later, but that is your choice)
2. You are nesting your case statements. You only want a single case statement, with multiple conditions. What you have is basically a nested if statement.
3. You never terminated the last case statement with an `ELSE` clause (I use `ELSE 0` below, but in some cases, `ELSE 1=0` OR `ELSE FALSE` might be needed to render a boolean value -- `ELSE NULL` should work too).
4. You have a `LEFT JOIN` that is converted into a `JOIN` because of the `WHERE` clause... I think that is what you actually want, but you should double check

The query should look more like this:

```
SELECT id_Cases, name, date_surgery, task_id, current
FROM cases
JOIN progress ON progress.case_id = cases.id_cases
WHERE archive = 0
  AND done = 0
  AND CASE name
    WHEN 'Cranioplasty' THEN task_id IN (103006, 103002) 
    WHEN 'Bone Tumor' THEN task_id = 201006 
    WHEN 'Osteotomy' THEN task_id = 301002 
    WHEN 'MBIO' THEN task_id = 401006 
    ELSE 0
  END
ORDER BY name, date_surgery;
```

I think this is what you want. If you really want the `LEFT JOIN`, it would look like this:

```
SELECT id_Cases, name, date_surgery, task_id, current
FROM cases
LEFT JOIN progress ON progress.case_id = cases.id_cases
    AND CASE name
      WHEN 'Cranioplasty' THEN task_id IN (103006, 103002) 
      WHEN 'Bone Tumor' THEN task_id = 201006 
      WHEN 'Osteotomy' THEN task_id = 301002 
      WHEN 'MBIO' THEN task_id = 401006 
      ELSE 0
    END
WHERE archive = 0
  AND done = 0
ORDER BY name, date_surgery;
```

Comment: It works almost as I want. With this code we search (for Cranioplasty) if task_id is either 103006 or 103002. What if I want both results?

Comment: it will show both a record for 103006 and 103002. If you only want an id_Cases that has BOTH tasks, then you would need to add something like this: `GROUP BY id_Cases HAVING IF(name = 'Cranioplasty, SUM(task_id=103006) AND SUM(task_id=103002), 1)'`. SUM here is ensuring that at least one record for the GROUPed id_Cases has the task_id. You could do it as `COUNT(IF(task_id=<#>, 1, 0))` but that is a lot more typing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can clearly state what task_ids are required for each name I suggest you capture this information in a new table. Let's call it `procedure_task`. Now you can include this new table with joins.

```
SELECT ...
FROM cases
JOIN progress ON progress.case_id = cases.id_cases
JOIN procedure_task ON cases.name = procedure_task.name
    AND progress.task_id = procedure_task.task_id
WHERE etc.
```

For each name only those tasks which are in the new table will be returned and multiple tasks can be returned per name.